# Template specialization with static constexpr member (function pointer)

Tags: c++, clang++

I have a class template which calls external functions in a C library. Depending on specialization (mostly `float` and `double`) it should call different functions. I can achieve this through template specialization. The code below compiles with gcc:

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++14 main.cpp -lm && ./a.out" -*-

#include <iostream>

extern "C" { // for illustration: not using cmath, but linking against libm
    float sinf(float);
    double sin(double);
}

template <typename T> struct Sin_callback;
template <> struct Sin_callback<float> { static constexpr auto sin_cb = sinf; };
template <> struct Sin_callback<double> { static constexpr auto sin_cb = sin; };

template <typename T> class Sin{
    static constexpr Sin_callback<T> m_cb {};
    T m_arg;
public:
    Sin(T&& arg): m_arg(arg) {}
    T calc() { return m_cb.sin_cb(m_arg); }
};

int main(){
    Sin<double> dbl(1.0);
    Sin<float> flt(1.0);
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << "ref:\t0.84147098480789650665" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double:\t" << dbl.calc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float:\t" << flt.calc() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output when using gcc 5.4:

```
ref:    0.84147098480789650665
double: 0.8414709848078965
float:  0.84147095680236816
```

but if I try to compile this using clang (both 3.8 and 4.0) compilation fails:

```
/tmp/main-75afd0.o: In function `Sin<double>::calc()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3SinIdE4calcEv[_ZN3SinIdE4calcEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `Sin_callback<double>::sin_cb'
/tmp/main-75afd0.o: In function `Sin<float>::calc()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3SinIfE4calcEv[_ZN3SinIfE4calcEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `Sin_callback<float>::sin_cb'
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I fail to understand why the specialization is not instantiated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang has trouble with static constexpr data members.

It all works if you convert the members to functions.

Here I have simply applied a call operator to the proxy function object.

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" { // for illustration: not using cmath, but linking against libm
float sinf(float);
double sin(double);
}

template<typename T>
struct Sin_callback;

template<>
struct Sin_callback<float> {
    template<class...Args>
    constexpr auto operator()(Args &&... args) const { return sinf(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

template<>
struct Sin_callback<double> {
    template<class...Args>
    constexpr auto operator()(Args &&... args) const { return sin(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

template<typename T>
class Sin {

    T m_arg;
public:
    Sin(T &&arg) : m_arg(arg) {}

    T calc() {
        constexpr Sin_callback<T> m_cb{};
        return m_cb(m_arg);
    }
};

int main() {
    Sin<double> dbl(1.0);
    Sin<float> flt(1.0);
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << "ref:\t0.84147098480789650665" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double:\t" << dbl.calc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "float:\t" << flt.calc() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
ref:    0.84147098480789650665
double: 0.8414709848078965
float:  0.84147095680236816
```

clang version:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Variadic templates helps a lot since my actual callbacks have a large number of arguments (functions from lapack). Just curious: do you know if my original code is standard conforming (i.e. this is a ``clang`` bug) or "undefined" behaviour (in which case I had hoped for ``gcc`` to warn me about it)?

Comment: @BjoernDahlgren i've never stopped to worry about whether it's standard-conforming - I'm too busy!. it might be a grey area to do with ODR-use. Add a language-lawyer tag to your question and one of the c++ committee guys might answer.